# Store value in multi-dimentional array on unique key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I display the following using the array shown below?

### Pastors

key=>0, member_id, member_name

### Deacons

key=>1, member_id, member_name
key=>2, member_id, member_name

Here is the array.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_name' => string 'Pastors' (length=7)
      'member_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'member_name' => string 'Tiny Marshall' (length=13)
      'member_email' => string 'jconley@nowhere.com' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_name' => string 'Deacons' (length=7)
      'member_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'member_name' => string 'Jeremiah Conley' (length=15)
      'member_email' => string 'jconley@nowhere.com' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'category_name' => string 'Deacons' (length=7)
      'member_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'member_name' => string 'Marcy Conley' (length=12)
      'member_email' => string 'jconley@nowhere.com' (length=19)
```

Here is the code that I used to build the array:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
{
    $staff[$i] = array
    (
        'category_name' => $row['category_name'],
        'member_id' => $row['member_id'],
        'member_name' => $row['member_name'],
        'member_email' => $row['member_email'],
    );
    $i++;
}
```

This is the final solution:

```
$category_name = array();       
    foreach ($staff as $member) {
        if (!in_array( $member['category_name'], $category_name )) 
        {
            echo '<h1>' . $member['category_name'] . '</h1>';
            $category_name[] = $member['category_name'];
        } 
        echo $member['member_id'] . ', ' . $member['member_name'] . '<br />';
    }
```

Comment: what would be the exact output from your given example?

Comment: The output you see above the while loop.

Comment: I mean what's the transformed result you need at the end?

Comment: Sorry. I want to show this:
Pastors
Tiny Marshall

Deacons
Jeremiah Conlney
Marcy Conley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` to loop over your $staff array.

```
$pastors = array();
$deacons = array();
foreach ($staff as $member) {
  if ($member['category_name'] == 'Pastors') {
    $pastors[] = $member['member_id'] . ', ' . $member['member_name'];
  } else if ($member['category_name'] == 'Deacons') {
    $deacons[] = $member['member_id'] . ', ' . $member['member_name'];
  }
}
```

[documentation](https://www.php.net//manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: What I want to do is display all staff where category == Pastors, display all staff where category == Deacons, etc. I may have to build the array differently to achieve the desired results.

Comment: @Cosmo, you can use an `if` statement to determine where to put the record. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. That got it pretty close. However, the categories will be updated often. I will not know what to look for every time. See my updated question for solution to final result.